# Ember User Token Management

Tags: session, ember.js

I am struggling a little with how I should implement a user authentication management in Ember JS. I would like to start with a very basic implementation.

```
# database table

users
-----
username, password, token
```

When the user attempts to sign in, they would provide credentials (username, password). The API which is requested should return a **token** and this token (in a header) should be used in every subsequent http request.

Couple of questions here:

- Where do I store the "token". Is there a local store management?
- I know I could use this.get('store') although this ties with the "api server data source" as well

Any direction would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use ember-simple-auth addon https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth

Comment: Yes, I am looking at it. Still does not answer all my questions though.

Comment: ember simple auth handles storing token for you using local storage, and it will handle placing token to any of your requests...

Comment: Right, reading through. Although I am unable to set the "store-data" in the authenticate method. Struggling with that.

Comment: Maybe you should post new question, or edit this one...